# Windows Installer for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-installer, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to install Windows Installer for Windows Server 2008 R2 X64. But when I installed Windows Installer 4.5 will display the following warning:

the update is not application to your computer

Answer (score 1):

Server 2008 and Win7 are by default using Windows Installer 5.0. The error message that you received appears because the MSI package which you are trying to install is corrupted, i.e. incomplete download, antivirus blocking the execution, etc... The first step would be to check its properties, file size, hash...

Answer (score 0):

That's because Windows Server 2008 R2 includes Windows Installer 4.5.

Comment: Why when I installed IIS 7.5 will display the following warning:  

This installation package could not be opened.
contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Comment: It sounds like something is corrupt.  Where exactly did you get that message?

Comment: I can not run .MSI files in My PC. Due to high alert.

Comment: Windows Installer 5 does not need to?

Comment: Similar topic: 

http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Cannot_install_Windows_Installer_4.5_on_Windows_Server_2008_R2/?TopicId=20190&Posts=2   


please give me link for download.